# How can I apply a vcl style to a TPanel?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, vcl-styles

I can change the appearance of VCL buttons by using the bit map stile designer with specifying a bitmap to [Objects]-[Button]-[Face]-[Bitmap].

So I tried to change the VCL panel's appearance in the same way with [Objects]-[Panel]-[Frame]-[Bitmap] and [Objects]-[Panel]-[FrameNoCaption]-[Bitmap].

The test dialog shows that buttons are rendered in an expected way, but panels are not.

How can I apply a VCL style to a TPanel?

Comment: Take a look at the "Glossy" style, which has a texture. However this will also apply to forms and almost any container surface.